# Is there a "keep above the surface" function in Blender that moves outwards any part of an object that might be hidden by another?

Tags: blender, modifier, shrinkwrap

I would like to keep my object always above the surface of another, even if part of the object moves inwards after updating its shapekeys. Exactly the same as the "keep above the surface" option in the Shrinkwrap modifier, but without the shrinking bit :)

Thanks.

[Updated]

Below you can see an image that hopefully explains more clearly what kind of result I'm looking for. I would like to find a way to bring out only parts of an object that might be hidden by another.
[image: On the left, you can see part of the dress inside the avatar. On the right, you can see the effect of the Shrinkwrap's "keep above surface" option]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [shrinkwrap constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/relationship/shrinkwrap.html). Unlike the shrinkwrap modifier, the constraint keeps the object origin on the surface of the target object. By [setting the object origin](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/origin.html) at the edge of your mesh you effectively keep the object on the surface.

[image: constraint panel]

[image: sample animation]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my question with an image that might make it clearer what I am looking for.